# Where can I find a CSS editor that runs in the browser?

Tags: webapp-rec

I would like to be able to edit some CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) directly into the browser. Some kind of plugin that I can take and use in my own application.

Either something that colourcodes the CSS as I type or something that has some kind of CSS wizard (like the one in Visual Studio), or both.

Comment: You mean edit and store on server side, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for, but one such CSS editor that allows you to write and test your own CSS in a browser is http://jsfiddle.net. Simply type your CSS on the top right box, then your html that uses the CSS in the top left box, then press "Run" on top. You will see the results in the bottom right box.

Comment: http://codemirror.net

Answer (score 0):

In FireFox, check out firebug. http://getfirebug.com/

In Safari or Chrome, just turn on web dev toolkit, and you can right click > inspect element, and edit away.

Comment: It needs to run for a user of a webapplication inside the browser. I found this http://codemirror.net

Answer (score 0):

http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ , this is add-on for firefox for view /edit CSS

Comment: It needs to run inside a webapplication, for the user of the webapplication I found this: http://codemirror.net

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if [Bespin](https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/) (or is it called Skywriter now?) does it, but that's pretty much as in-browser an editor goes.

Answer (score 0):

I've used unify (from unit interactive) a few times with success.  The last time I used it, however; it was very basic and didn't allow me to edit the general structure of the page.  Just things like color and size of textual elements.  It's possible this has been changed in more recent released.